# How to change the size and the numbers of keyboards

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

In an iPad app I need to change the keyboard. I want two keyboards, and everyone more little than the default iPad-sized keyboard. Can you help me people?

Comment: The only way to accomplish this is to implement a custom keyboard view and override the `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` method to show your custom view instead.

Comment: @BrianDriscoll Check out the `inputView` property of `UIResponder`.

Answer (score 0):

The *Text, Web, and Editing Programming Guide for iOS* has a section titled “[Input Views and Input Accessory Views](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/InputViews/InputViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH12-SW2)” that explains how to replace the standard keyboard with a custom view by setting the `inputView` property of your `UITextField` or `UITextView`.

You can find example code in the book *Beginning IPad Development for IPhone Developers: Mastering the IPad SDK*.

This stackoverflow question discusses replacing the standard keyboard by using a UIDatePicker as the `inputView`.